# How can I use Typescript to model an object via type instead of an interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following *JSON* which I have no control over:

```
{
    "date": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
    "a": 0,
    "b": 0,
    "c": 0
}
```

Instead of specifying an interface:

```
interface Foo {
    date: Date,
    "a": number,
    "b": number,
    "c": number
}
```

I want to be able to statically type the payload like so:

```
type Age = "a";
type Salary = "b";
type Height = "c"

type Foo = Record<"date", Date> | Record<Age | Salary | Height, number>;
```

Even though the compiler seems happy but when I try to get the **date** from the object I get the following error:

```
const foo = {
        "date": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
        "a": 0,
        "b": 0,
        "c": 0
    } as Foo;
```

> Element implicitly has 'any' type.

If I remove the `Record<Age | Salary | Height, number>` then the error goes away.

Comment: can you specify which element reported to implicitly has `any` type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) instead of [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types):

```
type Foo = Record<"date", string> & Record<Age | Salary | Height, number>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAgg5tAvFARAQxQbgFCklAZTQBs0AnEKZFAIy13GgAkIBLOAC2CtQGMVsDfADEA9qJ4AlCL1FkAJgB4U8tMAgoANFADOwMqwB2cAHxQAZFGmyFi+NAA+hEuUpOW7LtsMBXALY0EGQmgrKGelAAZuI8AN7YUImoquooAFyoAEwADDkAtNkAjAWFACrZ2WkVVdlaCUno6VDZmvWJtE0tbXyd2AC+UGg6UGKiONjRogB0KRCYQA)

---

** I've changed `date` type to `string` because you're assigning string value to this field